How to pull in ALL connector changes?
I find that only certain changes to my connector Apps Script are respected when refreshing the connector in the data source.
For example, if I change the value in setName, from:
fields.newMetric().setId('A').setName('Metric A')

To
fields.newMetric().setId('A').setName('Field A')

When I go to refresh my connector, it simply states that there are no changes. Does anyone know if there is a way to force these changes to be respected?
And just to vent: the Looker Studio Help Community has been down for two months now. Past questions here and there have gone unanswered. New functionality released is not what the community has requested, and is often half baked and not returned to. Highly requested functionality has been starred and assigned for years in many cases, publicly available in their issue tracker. What is happening with Google is so disappointing.
